# Java Parameters, If-then statements, loops

Tags: java

I was given directions to write a method that takes two parameters. If the first parameter is equal to second parameter. Multiply both and print result.

If the first parameter is less than the second parameter, add the two and print the result 10 times.

If the first parameter is greater than the second parameter, subtract the first parameter from the second and print the result 50 times.

This is what I've coded:

```
public class IfHomeworkRedo {

{

public static void two(int a, int b) {

    if (a == b) System.out.println(a*b);

    else if (a < b) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            System.out.println(a+b);

        }
    }

   else if (a > b) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            System.out.println(b-a);



    }

}




public static void main (String[] args)

{

    two(3, 3);

    two(3, 4);

    two(4, 3);

}

}
```

Can you help me with the errors? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please copy the code into your question, so that this question can be useful to others later on, even if the ideone.com site (or your link) goes down. You'll find that [so] has wonderful code formatting. Just make sure to indent your code by 4 spaces, and put an empty line before and after.

Comment: You should definitely make your homeworks on your own: I bet your teacher will be eager to help you with errors if you ask him/her.

Comment: I did all of this myself I just need help on the errors.

Comment: There are two `{{` after the class declaration and before the `two` method declaration, start by getting rid of one.  You will need to add a `}` after the `two` method and before the `main` method

Answer (score 1):

There should be no `public` on the class (if using ideone), and you had misplaced brackets. Solution: (http://ideone.com/7wBaSF)

```
class IfHomeworkRedo {

    public static void main (String[] args)

    {

        two(3, 3);

        two(3, 4);

        two(4, 3);

    }

    public static void two(int a, int b) {

        if (a == b) {System.out.println(a*b);}

        else if (a < b) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                System.out.println(a+b);

            }
        }

       else if (a > b) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                System.out.println(b-a);



            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This at least fixed your syntax errors; you will still need to check logical errors, if they exist.

Comment: *"There should be no public on the class"* - Why?

Comment: I think it is a quirk with the ideone site; sometimes they have weird requirements on class declarations. When keeping the `public` keyword, it returns an error about storing the class in a file. In an application-based scenario, public would be used.

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with the problems the OP is having then?

Comment: Exactly; if they were to use a standard IDE, then the only corrections to be made would be to the brackets (updated answer to reflect this).

Answer (score 1):

## Problem #1

```
public class IfHomeworkRedo {
{
public static void two(int a, int b) {
```

There are two `{{` before the `two` method declaration, you need to get rid of one

```
public class IfHomeworkRedo {

    public static void two(int a, int b) {
```

## Problem #2

You're missing a closing `}` after the end of the `two` method...

```
public static void two(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) System.out.println(a*b);
    else if (a < b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(a+b);
        }
    }
        else if (a > b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println(b-a);
        }
    }
//??? Add } here
```

As general advice, it's easier to wrap all logic in a `{...}`, even it's just one line, as it will make it easier to read and reduce the risk on introducing logic errors, for example...

```
public static void two(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        System.out.println(a * b);
    } else if (a < b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(a + b);
        }
    } else if (a > b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println(b - a);
        }
    }
}
```